# .profileの末尾にexit0を記載してしまった

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

Raspberry Piでrc.localと間違えて.profileの末尾にexit 0と記載し再起動したところ、ログインしてもすぐに再びログイン画面に戻ってしまう無限ループ状態になってしまったのですが、元の状態に戻す手立てはないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

とりあえず、思い付いた方法を3つ。

#### 別のマシンで `.profile` を編集する

Raspberry Pi で使用している SD カードの Linux のパーテーションをマウントできるマシンを用意します。
そのマシンに SD カードを接続し、問題の `.profile` を編集します。
（必ずしも別のマシンでなくとも、問題の物とは別のストレージからブートすれば当該のRaspberry Pi で構いません）

#### シングルユーザーモードで起動する

Linux での一般的なリカバリー方法です。
まず、シングルユーザーモードで起動し、修正対象のパーテーションを書き込み可でマウントして作業をするのが流れです。
シングルユーザーモードで起動する方法は使用しているブートローダーによって変わります。

Raspberry Pi の場合は、SD カードのブート用のパーテーション（このパーテーションだけは FAT系になっており、Windows などでも編集が可能になっています）にある `cmdline.txt` を編集し、カーネルの起動パラメーターに `init=/bin/sh` を加える方法が一般的なようです。

参考:
http://www.programming-knowledge.com/Raspberry_Pi_and_Linux_Tips
http://denki.nara-edu.ac.jp/~yabu/soft/pi.html#50

#### SSH 経由で作業する

ssh でログインできる設定が済んでいれば、いくつか方法があります。
例えば、

```sh
# .profile の読み込みを抑止する
# -t オプションを付けると疑似端末が割り当てられ、画面を制御するコマンドも正常に動くようになるようです
# （metropolis さんのコメント参照）
ssh USER@HOST -t 'bash --noprofile'

# 手元の .profile で上書きする
scp ./.profile USER@HOST:~/.profile
```

などです。

Comment: `ssh USER@HOST 'bash --noprofile'` についてですが、ssh に `-t` オプション(force pseudo-terminal allocation)を付ければプロンプトが表示される様になります。おそらく、vi などによる編集作業も通常通りできるかと。